# Does Firebase Allow Address Book Access?

Tags: firebase

If you look at this question:
[Firebase one to one chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416894/firebase-one-to-one-chat)

You will see in the comment:

> It sounds like your application will need to access the address book of the user's phone, which is something Firebase security rules cannot do (since they run on the Firebase server).

Is this true?

Comment: *not the downvoter* Hi Aneel. Your question is a bit unclear. The Device Address book is separate from Firebase DB. What are you referring to?

Comment: Firebase security rules run on the server. They have no access to the address book of your Android device. As AL said: accessing the Address Book on the device itself is possible, but has nothing to do with Firebase.

Comment: If you run the Firebase Friendly Chat sample code in Android Studio you will see that AppInvite can open the phone's contacts. However, it cannot return a handle to a contact to the program, and it cannot receive one. The article I referred to seems to say that if your Android app is using Firebase as a back-end, its security will stop you from letting the app open the phone's contacts. Is this what the article is saying, and if so, is it true.  
Have you personally opened, in your app, the Contacts on a user's phone when you were using Firebase as a back-end?

Answer (score 0):

firebase security rules are for the database only that mean it's server side, book address is client side not server side, so yes you can't do it with firebase you have to make take permission in your application